# Dynamic queryset filtering with multiple query parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view I have implemented to filter transactions depending on a certain query provided. Is there a way I could filter dynamically depending on what query is provided, for example one would want to only query `year` and `month` only or even filter using one query. The rest of the query values will end up having a `None` value an should not be included in the filter.

```
class ReportTransactionsFilterAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        year = self.request.GET.get('year')
        month = self.request.GET.get('month')
        subcounty = self.request.GET.get('subcounty')
        ward = self.request.GET.get('ward')

        fromDate = self.request.GET.get('fromDate')
        toDate = self.request.GET.get('toDate')   

        qs = LiquorReceiptTrack.objects.all()
        qs = LiquorReceiptTrack.objects.filter(
            Q(date_recieved__range=[fromDate,toDate])|
            Q(date_recieved__year=year)|
            Q(date_recieved__month=month)|
            Q(sub_county__iexact=subcounty)|
            Q(ward__iexact=ward)

        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for your solution. Also for more information you can visit https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if`, why `Q` do you use here?:

```
year = self.request.GET.get('year')
month = self.request.GET.get('month')
subcounty = self.request.GET.get('subcounty')
ward = self.request.GET.get('ward')

fromDate = self.request.GET.get('fromDate')
toDate = self.request.GET.get('toDate')   

qs = LiquorReceiptTrack.objects.all()
if year:
    qs = qs.filter(date_recieved__year=year)
if month:
    qs = qs.filter(date_recieved__month=month)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Went over the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) documentation and refactored the list view:

```
class TransactionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    date_range = DateFromToRangeFilter()
    month = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_recieved', lookup_expr='month')
    year = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date_recieved', lookup_expr='year')
    date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='date_recieved', lookup_expr='exact')
    sub_county = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    ward = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')


    class Meta:
        model = LiquorReceiptTrack
        fields = ['date','month','year','date_range','sub_county','ward']

class ReportTransactionsFilterAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):


    queryset = LiquorReceiptTrack.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReceiptDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = TransactionFilter
```